# can pimpl idiom's impl class has destructor？

Tags: c++11, effective-c++

I learn pimpl in effective modern cpp,after do some search,no one has talk about the pimpl idiom's impl class's destructor implement, is it unnecessary?

```
//in widget.h
#include <memory>
class Widget{
public:
    Widget();
private:
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> pImpl;
};
//in widget.cpp
........
struct Widget::Impl{
  std::string name;                // Widget::Impl
  std::vector<double> data;
};


struct Widget::~Impl()   //error!!!,how can we implement it
{
};
```

Comment: You're missing `()` among other things.  https://ideone.com/bWKTTC

Comment: In this case specifically then yes the dtor is useless (both string and vector manage their memory themselves)

Comment: You can make a destructor if you want... good class design normaly involves not requiring your own destructor

Answer (score 0):

The PIMPL idiom's implementation interface structure cannot be declared as a `private` field of a class. Also, the declaration of a `unique_ptr` to an incomplete datatype is not allowed in C++ so we have to opt for plain old pointers to declare the PIMPL and manually `new` and `delete` it appropriately.

The destructor of the `struct Impl` can be defined like this in `widget.cpp`:

```
Widget::Impl::~Impl()
{

};
```

The final code may look something like this:

### widget.h

```
class Widget
{
public:
    Widget();
    ~Widget();
    struct Impl;
private:
    Impl* pImpl;
};
```

### widget.cpp

```
struct Widget::Impl
{
  Impl();
  std::string name;                // Widget::Impl
  std::vector<double> data;

  ~Impl();
};

//Widget Impl Constructor  
Widget::Impl::Impl()
{

}

//Widget Impl Destructor
Widget::Impl::~Impl()
{

};

//Widget Constructor
Widget::Widget() : pImpl(nullptr)
{
    pImpl = new Impl();
}

//Widget Destructor
Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete pImpl;
    pImpl = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: unique_ptr can accept Impl if we make sure that the point where the code to destroy unique_ptr<Impl> ,the Widget::Impl is a complete type.To finish this ,we can define Widget Destructor after Widget::Impl is defined.

Comment: This blog post provides more details about that: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/09/22/make-pimpl-using-unique_ptr/

Answer (score 0):

thanks for [demo](https://ideone.com/bWKTTC)code post by @Retired Ninja,it helps a lot,the point is,we need a declaration of ~Impl in the cpp file:

```
Widget::Widget():pImpl(std::make_unique<Impl>())
{
}

 struct Widget::Impl {
     std::string name;
     std::vector<double> data;
     ~Impl();// need this !!
 };

 Widget::Impl::~Impl(){
 };

 Widget::~Widget() {
 }
```